# How to rename flutter project safely using pub.dev package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My Operating System is Linux Fedora 38. I'm using:

- android studio 2022.3.1 .
- code 1.82.2 .
- Flutter 3.13.0 .
- Dart 3.1.0 .
  My problem is shown when:

i ***rename*** flutter project name to another one have a lot of problem.
i tryed to do that manualy and changed it in

- `pubspec.yaml`
- `AndroidManifest.xml`
  but i faced a lot of problem after did that.

i want to rename my project to another name in arabic without problem maybe using one of  pub.dev packages.

Comment: Have you tried this package https://pub.dev/packages/rename

Comment: I am not comfortable using it because it requires the use of global permissions.

Comment: I think it's best to change it manually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way to do that by using rename_app package.

My new name = "سلام".

Install the package

```
flutter pub add rename_app
```

Change the name of android package

```
flutter pub run rename_app:main android="سلام"
```